# Plot in R language

Tags: r, plot, iteration

I have instruction for R console:

```
plot(1:1000, some_function(1000,1/2,500, type='l')
```

Can someone explain to me what 1:1000 means? I tried to put some other input instead of 1:1000, for example 1:100 but then it won't work.

I understand that 1:1000 means it will iterate from 1 to 1000, but what does that mean as a plot argument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1:1000` is your `x` axis. We usually do `?plot` or `help("plot")` in order to understand what a function does.

Comment: So 1:1000 is basically same as xlim=c(1,1000) ?

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић No. Please follow David's advice.

Comment: Please read [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) to learn these basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a vector with the elements from 1 to 1000; therefore, a 1000-element vector.

For the plot function, the first argument corresponds to the x coordinates of the points to be added. Hence, `1:1000` means that the data points will have x coordinates `1, 2, ..., 1000`

Comment: You mean plot will have 1000 dots?

Comment: Yes, the x coordinates will be `1, 2, 3, ..., 1000`, and y coordinates corresponding to the vector returned by `some_function(1000,1/2,500)`

Comment: Note, however, that you have a mistake in the command. It should be `plot(1:1000, some_function(1000,1/2,500), type='l')`

Comment: Typing mistake. So in this case you HAVE TO call some function 1000 times in order to work?

Comment: Or at least you have to return vector with 1000 elements?

Comment: Yes, the vectors specifying the `x` and `y` coordinates should have equal lengths. You need to understand the expected format of the arguments. Please follow the advice by David Arenburg and check the help for the function.

Comment: I've done that before I posted question. Anyway, thanks for the answer.